# What resistors and capacity do I need for TSOP382 IR Sensors?

Tags: wireless, sensor

I'm not sure if this is necessary but this doc tells me that I have to put some R's and C's in the circuit:

[TSOP382 IR Receiver Modules for Remote Control Systems](https://www.vishay.com/docs/82491/tsop382.pdf) (Datasheet PDF)

[image]

How do I know what value I need? And what is that µC thingy that is not explained?

Thanks for helping
Mike

Comment: µC = Microprocessor.

Answer (score 4):

µC is an abbreviation for microcontroller and just means the device you are using to read the signal (in this case the Raspberry Pi).

The capacitors and resistors aren't really needed for a hobby application.  I never bother.

Power from a 3V3 pin and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wasn't aware of this abbreviation so thanks for explaining this. In my current setup everything's working fine without R's and C's so I think you are right. I'm interested in the correct way of using things so I wanted to ask here...

Comment: @Mike1993 For the correct way you are more likely to get a proper answer at electronics stack exchange.  The legend does suggest the R & C are only needed if the power voltage is less than 2.8V.